# How do I control float property on div

Tags: css, html

I'm doing this simple web page and I'm having a problem while trying to set float:left to a bunch of div's. I created the class aluno and applied float:left, the problem is that other div's from other classes following this one also got floated to the left. What can I do to prevent this ?

My html code:

```
<div class ="main">
    <div class = "aluno">
        <p>
            Cena
            <button type="button" onclick="show('img')">+</button>
        </p>
        <p><img id="img1" src="img/img1.png" ></p>
    </div>

    <div class = "aluno">
        <p>
            Cena
            <button type="button" onclick="show('img')">+</button>
        </p>
        <p><img id="img" src="img/img.png"></p>
    </div>

<div class = "teste">
</div>
```

My css code:

```
.aluno{
    float:left;
    padding-left: 70px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `clear:both` to `.teste`.

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to
>   floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared)
>   below them.

```
  .teste{
       clear: both;
    }
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LhtrC/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float:none` on your other classes.

Comment: I tried, but it still remains on the right side of the last div block of aluno class.